# Can Swift convert a class / struct data into dictionary?

Tags: swift, class, object, dictionary

For example:

```
class Test {
    var name: String;
    var age: Int;
    var height: Double;
    func convertToDict() -> [String: AnyObject] { ..... }
}

let test = Test();
test.name = "Alex";
test.age = 30;
test.height = 170;

let dict = test.convertToDict();
```

dict will have content:

```
{"name": "Alex", "age": 30, height: 170}
```

Is this possible in Swift?

And can I access a class like a dictionary, for example probably using:

```
test.value(forKey: "name");
```

Or something like that?

Comment: Why do you want to? You can use key paths directly on the class/struct. So what's the point here? In what way would a dictionary be "better" than a class/struct? "And can I access a class like a dictionary" Yes, exactly, using key paths, in Swift 4.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use Swift’s Codable to encode into a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45209743/how-can-i-use-swift-s-codable-to-encode-into-a-dictionary)

Comment: You want to do conversion for what purpose?  If you are going to save your data, you should create a model with a class.  Converting a struct into Data will be more troubling.

Comment: I want to do the conversion for JSON encoding and passing values between ViewController purpose. From the accepted answer, I believe the `Encodable` is the key.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can just add a computed property to your `struct` to return a `Dictionary` with your values. Note that Swift native dictionary type doesn't have any method called `value(forKey:)`. You would need to cast your `Dictionary` to `NSDictionary`:

```
struct Test {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
    let height: Double
    var dictionary: [String: Any] {
        return ["name": name,
                "age": age,
                "height": height]
    }
    var nsDictionary: NSDictionary {
        return dictionary as NSDictionary
    }
}
```

---

You can also extend `Encodable` protocol as suggested at the linked answer posted by @ColGraff to make it universal to all `Encodable` structs:

```
struct JSON {
    static let encoder = JSONEncoder()
}
extension Encodable {
    subscript(key: String) -> Any? {
        return dictionary[key]
    }
    var dictionary: [String: Any] {
        return (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSON.encoder.encode(self))) as? [String: Any] ?? [:]
    }
}
```

---

```
struct Test: Codable {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
    let height: Double
}

let test = Test(name: "Alex", age: 30, height: 170)
test["name"]    // Alex
test["age"]     // 30
test["height"]  // 170
```

Comment: Actually, I use the example `value(forKey` just to illustrate what I need, which is querying an object to get the value of its properties by using a variable keys instead of hard-coded one. I don't plan to use `NSDictionary`. I plan to use this in conjunction with JSON, so I believe your `Encodable` protocol works best for my problem. I don't know about the keyword to search about this type of problem, but now I do. I know I can create a personalized function to return custom dictionary for each class, I just wondering if there's a universal method to do this. Thanks!!

Comment: The Encodable extension approach is elegant! Thank you Leo.

Comment: Thanks This work for me
extension Encodable {
    var dictionaryObj: [String: Any] {
        return (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSON.encoder.encode(self))) as? [String: Any] ?? [:]
    }
}

Comment: why is it accepted as answer? "if you need to convert to dictionary then create a func which returns your dictionary manually each time you need it"

Answer (score 44):

You could use Reflection and Mirror like this to make it more dynamic and ensure you do not forget a property.

```
struct Person {
  var name:String
  var position:Int
  var good : Bool
  var car : String

  var asDictionary : [String:Any] {
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
    let dict = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: mirror.children.lazy.map({ (label:String?, value:Any) -> (String, Any)? in
      guard let label = label else { return nil }
      return (label, value)
    }).compactMap { $0 })
    return dict
  }
}


let p1 = Person(name: "Ryan", position: 2, good : true, car:"Ford")
print(p1.asDictionary)
```

["name": "Ryan", "position": 2, "good": true, "car": "Ford"]

Comment: How does it work when there are nested struct? I mean let us say there is another struct Company with field like name, location, id etc. and the struct Person has a property company: Company. Then how does this mirroring logic work?

Comment: Is there a way to remove some of the items from listing -> key: optional("value")?

Comment: Removing the optionals

Answer (score 9):

A bit late to the party, but I think this is a great opportunity for `JSONEncoder` and `JSONSerialization`.
The accepted answer does touch on this, this solution saves us calling `JSONSerialization` every time we access a key, but same idea!

```swift
extension Encodable {
    
    /// Encode into JSON and return `Data`
    func jsonData() throws -> Data {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
        encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .iso8601
        return try encoder.encode(self)
    }
}
```

You can then use `JSONSerialization` to create a `Dictionary` if the `Encodable` should be represented as an object in JSON (e.g. Swift `Array` would be a JSON array).

Here's an example:

```swift
struct Car: Encodable {
    var name: String
    var numberOfDoors: Int
    var cost: Double
    var isCompanyCar: Bool
    var datePurchased: Date
    var ownerName: String? // Optional
}

let car = Car(
    name: "Mazda 2",
    numberOfDoors: 5,
    cost: 1234.56,
    isCompanyCar: true,
    datePurchased: Date(),
    ownerName: nil
)

// Get the encoded JSON data
let jsonData = try car.jsonData()
    
// To get a dictionary from the JSON data
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])
guard let dictionary = json as? [String : Any] else { return }
    
// Use dictionary...

// Print jsonString
guard let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) else { return }
print(jsonString)
```

Output:

```json
{
  "numberOfDoors" : 5,
  "datePurchased" : "2020-03-04T16:04:13Z",
  "name" : "Mazda 2",
  "cost" : 1234.5599999999999,
  "isCompanyCar" : true
}
```

Comment: why do you write `try` for encoding but throw nothing and just return when the resulting json doesn't contain a dictionary?

Comment: Hey @Gargo, for simplicity. I just wanted to demonstrate a simple and working example. In a production project I would, like you say, turn the guard-returns into a custom error that is thrown to be handled by the caller. I don't need to burden the reader with understanding my custom errors here.

Comment: I think you should at least add a comment "or throw an error". Another reason is Objective-C main way to handle errors didn't involve exceptions. Swift vice versa usually use exceptions. So it is slightly confusing if you use both ways simultaneously in the same chunk of code.

Answer (score 3):

Use protocol, it is an elegant solution.
 1. encode struct or class to data 
2. decode data and transfer to dictionary.

```
/// define protocol convert Struct or Class to Dictionary
protocol Convertable: Codable {

}

extension Convertable {

    /// implement convert Struct or Class to Dictionary
    func convertToDict() -> Dictionary<String, Any>? {

        var dict: Dictionary<String, Any>? = nil

        do {
            print("init student")
            let encoder = JSONEncoder()

            let data = try encoder.encode(self)
            print("struct convert to data")

            dict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? Dictionary<String, Any>

        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        return dict
    }
}

struct Student: Convertable {

    var name: String
    var age: Int
    var classRoom: String

    init(_ name: String, age: Int, classRoom: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.classRoom = classRoom
    }
}

let student = Student("zgpeace", age: 18, classRoom: "class one")

print(student.convertToDict() ?? "nil")
```

ref: https://a1049145827.github.io/2018/03/02/Swift-%E4%BB%8E%E9%9B%B6%E5%AE%9E%E7%8E%B0%E4%B8%80%E4%B8%AAStruct%E6%88%96Class%E8%BD%ACDictionary%E7%9A%84%E9%9C%80%E6%B1%82/

Answer (score 3):

This answer is like the [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54671872/1261661) which uses Mirror. But consider the nested class/struct case.

```swift
extension Encodable {
    func dictionary() -> [String:Any] {
        var dict = [String:Any]()
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        for child in mirror.children {
            guard let key = child.label else { continue }
            let childMirror = Mirror(reflecting: child.value)
            
            switch childMirror.displayStyle {
            case .struct, .class:
                let childDict = (child.value as! Encodable).dictionary()
                dict[key] = childDict
            case .collection:
                let childArray = (child.value as! [Encodable]).map({ $0.dictionary() })
                dict[key] = childArray
            case .set:
                let childArray = (child.value as! Set<AnyHashable>).map({ ($0 as! Encodable).dictionary() })
                dict[key] = childArray
            default:
                dict[key] = child.value
            }
        }
        
        return dict
    }
}
```