# Codable Struct: Get Value by Key

Tags: swift, key-value-coding

I have for example codable struct `User`:

```
struct User: Codable {
    // ...
    var psnTag: String?
    var xblTag: String?
    var steamTag: String?
    var nintendoTag: String?
    var instagramId: String?
    // ...
}
```

and stringKey as `String` = "psnTag"

How can I get the value from instance by stringKey?

Like this:

```
let stringKey = "psnTag"
user.hasKeyForPath(stringKey) //return Bool
user.valueForPath(stringKey) //return AnyObject
```

Comment: A string key path is *objective-c-ish* and error-prone. You (the developer) are supposed to know at **design** time if *user.hasKeyForPath*. That's another pretty expensive unnecessary runtime check. This is Swift. **Take care of types**. Use native Swift `Keypath` e.g. `let keyPath = \User.psnTag`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46597941/2303865 if you would like to implement those method for any Codable struct after adding the extensions in that post `extension Encodable {
    func hasKey(for path: String) -> Bool {
        return self[path] != nil
    }
    func value(for path: String) -> Any? {
        return self[path]
    }
}`

Answer (score 5):

Start with extending `Encodable` protocol and declare methods for `hasKey` and for `value`

#### Using Mirror

```
extension Encodable {
    func hasKey(for path: String) -> Bool {
        return Mirror(reflecting: self).children.contains { $0.label == path }
    }
    func value(for path: String) -> Any? {
        return Mirror(reflecting: self).children.first { $0.label == path }?.value
    }
}
```

#### Using JSON Serialization

```
extension Encodable {
    func hasKey(for path: String) -> Bool {
        return dictionary?[path] != nil
    }
    func value(for path: String) -> Any? {
        return dictionary?[path]
    }    
    var dictionary: [String: Any]? {
        return (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONEncoder().encode(self))) as? [String: Any]
    }
}
```

---

Now you can use it like this:

```
.hasKey(for: "key") //returns Bool
.value(for: "key") //returns Any?
```

Comment: you could simply extend Encodable

Comment: @LeoDabus btw, once OP wants to use function,  I don't think that `subscript` is good way. But again, I can be wrong.

Comment: The previous comment had a typo `extension Encodable {
    subscript(_ key: String) -> Any? {
        return (Mirror(reflecting: self).children.first { $0.label == key })?.value
    }
}`

Comment: Using `Mirror` in production code just to implement a conversion to dictionary seems a bit too complicated.