# Get coding value for a Codable value in Swift

Tags: swift, swift-keypath

I am working on a Swift service that stores codable types in JSON. The type also defines a nested `CodingKeys` enum to define the property names when coded to JSON. For example, I might have a type that looks like this:

```
struct MyType : Codable {
  let myIntProperty: Int
  let myStringProperty: String

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case myIntProperty = "int_property"
    case myStringProperty = "string_property"
  }
}
```

Now I have a function that wants to operate on one of these properties, as specified by a key path to that property. Using the type from the example, I want a function that can be called like this:

```
 let result = myFunc(usingProperty: \MyType.myIntProperty)
```

My function is declared using the `KeyPath` type:

```
func myFunc<T: Codable, G>(usingProperty: KeyPath<T, G>) -> G {
  ...
}
```

In order to implement my function, I would like to somehow get access to not just the key path parameter named `usingProperty`, but also to the coding key that it is associated with. So when called with the key path to the `myIntProperty` property, I would want to get the name used when encoding it, which is `int_property`.

Is there any way to derive this value from the `KeyPath` parameter and its root type's `CodingKeys` enumeration?

Comment: Why would you need to get something that you know already what it is?

Comment: @LeoDabus the function that needs it does NOT know what it is. It needs both the key path (to operate on the Codable objects) and the encoded name (to operate on the associated JSON)

Comment: maybe you will use mirror to convert your object to dictionary so you can access to the property that you want.

Comment: @TimDean this might help [Can Swift convert a class / struct data into dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46597941/2303865)

Comment: Thanks @LeoDabus but that link only seems to provide an elegant place to put the code I need (in an extension to Codable) but doesn't provide anything to help me figure out what code I need to write.

Comment: @TimDean No body can guess if you don't add a practical example of what you are trying to achieve. Again you shouldn't need the keys. Why do you think CodingKeys are private when it is automatically synthesized by a struct?

Comment: @LeoDabus - Sorry, but I guess I don't understand what is missing from my question. The practical example is right there in the question. Not sure what you mean when you suggest I think "CodingKeys are private"

Comment: @TimDean I suggest forget about keypath and use a dictionary. Codable won't help IMO. But you can use the protocol if you want as shown in that post