# Map an array of objects in Firestore to an a dictionary array in swift

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

My data structure looks like this below with a document containing some fields and an array of "business hours":
[image]

The parent struct looks like this:

```
protocol RestaurantSerializable {
    init?(dictionary:[String:Any], restaurantId : String)
}

struct Restaurant {
    var distance: Double
    var distributionType : Int
    var businessHours : Array<BusinessHours>

var dictionary: [String: Any] {
        return [
            "distance": distance,
            "distributionType": distributionType,
            "businessHours": businessHours.map({$0.dictionary})
        ]
    }
}

extension Restaurant : RestaurantSerializable {
    init?(dictionary: [String : Any], restaurantId: String) {
        guard let distance = dictionary["distance"] as? Double,
            let distributionType = dictionary["distributionType"] as? Int,
        let businessHours = dictionary["businessHours"] as? Array<BusinessHours>
        
            else { return nil }
         
self.init(distance: distance, geoPoint: geoPoint, distributionType: distributionType, businessHours, restaurantId : restaurantId)
       }
}
```

And here is the business hours struct:

```
protocol BusinessHoursSerializable {
    init?(dictionary:[String:Any])
}

struct BusinessHours : Codable {
    var selected : Bool
    var thisDay : String
    var startHour : Int
    var closeHour : Int
    
    var dictionary : [String : Any] {
        return [
            "selected" : selected,
            "thisDay" : thisDay,
            "startHour" : startHour,
            "closeHour" : closeHour
        ]
    }
}

extension BusinessHours : BusinessHoursSerializable {
    init?(dictionary : [String : Any]) {
        guard let selected = dictionary["selected"] as? Bool,
        let thisDay = dictionary["thisDay"] as? String,
        let startHour = dictionary["startHour"] as? Int,
        let closeHour = dictionary["closeHour"] as? Int

            else { return nil }
        
        self.init(selected: selected, thisDay: thisDay, startHour: startHour, closeHour: closeHour)
        
    }
}
```

I am trying to query the DB as such:

```
db.whereField("users", arrayContains: userId).getDocuments() { documentSnapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                completion([], error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                restaurantArray.append(contentsOf: (documentSnapshot?.documents.compactMap({ (restaurantDocument) -> Restaurant in
                    Restaurant(dictionary: restaurantDocument.data(), restaurantId: restaurantDocument.documentID)!
                }))!)
}
```

And even though I have data, I keep getting this error on the last line above:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

If I put a default value then all I get is the default value. How do I get the array of objects from the flat JSON?

I tried to obtain each individual field. And then parse through the business hours field but that seems inefficient. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: When you create `Restaurant` instance, what does `restaurantDocument.data()` contain? Does it contain `businessHours` field, and in which form? You force unwrap the `Restaurant` object which constructor can return `nil` if the `BusinessHours` is not a dictionary. I would recommend to avoid forced unwrapping wherever you can – this way your app won't crash.

Comment: If I don't force unwrap it, I get an empty array.

Comment: The reason for that is only that your optional is `nil` and thus the provided default is used. Empty array is still much better than a fatal error from the end-user perspective :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is at the place where you cast the `businessHours`:

```swift
let businessHours = dictionary["businessHours"] as? Array<BusinessHours>
```

The actual data seems to be an array, but of the dictionaries, containing the hours, not the `BusinessHours` obejcts. That's why guard fails, `Restaurant` init returns `nil` and the code fails on unwrapping.

I've found a good implementation of more general dictionary serialization [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46329055/853389), and based on that created the code example that should work for you:

```swift
  /// A protocol to signify the types you need to be dictionaty codable
  protocol DictionaryCodable: Codable {
  }
  
  /// The extension that actually implements the bi-directional dictionary encoding
  /// via JSON serialization
  extension DictionaryCodable {
    /// Returns optional dictionary if the encoding succeeds
    var dictionary: [String: Any]? {
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self) else {
            return nil
        }
        return try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]
    }
    /// Creates the instance of self decoded from the given dictionary, or nil on failure
    static func decode(from dictionary:[String:Any]) -> Self? {
        guard let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary, options: .fragmentsAllowed) else {
            return nil
        }
        return try? JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: data)
    }
  }
  
  // Your structs now have no special code to serialze or deserialize,
  // but only need to conform to DictionaryCodable protocol
  
  struct BusinessHours : DictionaryCodable {
      var selected : Bool
      var thisDay : String
      var startHour : Int
      var closeHour : Int
  }

  struct Restaurant: DictionaryCodable {
      var distance: Double
      var distributionType : Int
      var businessHours : [BusinessHours]
  }

  // This is the example of a Restaurant
  
  let r1 = Restaurant(distance: 0.1, distributionType: 1, businessHours: [
    BusinessHours(selected: false, thisDay: "Sun", startHour: 10, closeHour: 23),
    BusinessHours(selected: true, thisDay: "Mon", startHour: 11, closeHour: 18),
    BusinessHours(selected: true, thisDay: "Tue", startHour: 11, closeHour: 18),
  ])
  
  // This is how it can be serialized
  guard let dictionary = r1.dictionary else {
        print("Error encoding object")
        return
  }
  
  // Check the result
  print(dictionary)

  // This is how it can be deserialized directly to the object
  guard let r2 = Restaurant.decode(from: dictionary) else {
    print("Error decoding the object")
    return
  }
  
  // Check the result
  print(r2)
```

To avoid app crash on force unwraps (it's still better to show no results, than crash), I would recommend slightly changing the sequence of calls you use for data retrieval from the database:

```swift
db.whereField("users", arrayContains: userId).getDocuments() { documentSnapshot, error in
  guard nil == error else {
    // We can force unwrap the error here because it definitely exists
    completion([], error!.localizedDescription)
    return
  }

    // compactMap will get rid of improperly constructed Restaurant instances,
    // it will not get executed if documentSnapshot is nil
    // you only append non-nil Restaurant instances to the restaurantArray.
    // Worst case scenario you will end up with an unchanged restaurantArray.
    restaurantArray.append(contentsOf: documentSnapshot?.documents.compactMap { restaurantDocument in
        Restaurant.decode(from: restaurantDocument.data())
    } ?? [])
}
```

Comment: Query for one document has documentSnapshot where query for collection has querySnapshot. (It's recommended to follow default value names, because "real" documentSnapshot has no document property)