# How do I reference fields in a self defined NSObject?

Tags: swift, nsobject

Looking for assistance since I am missing something!  I have defined a new object called "User".

```
class User: NSObject {

    var userID: String!
    var fullname: String!
    var imagePath: String!
}
```

Now I want to iterate through each object one at a time checking the values of some of the fields.

```
func retrieveUsers() {
        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("users").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
            let users = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
            self.user.removeAll()
            
            for (key,value) in users {
    // HOW DO I REFERENCE A FIELD IN THE USER OBJECT
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that in your code, your `users` object is of type `[String:AnyObject]` since you're grabbing it from a database (Firebase?).

So, you have an untyped Dictionary to deal with.

You can reference fields on the dictionary by doing users[key] where `key` is a `String.`

Judging by your naming of variables, it looks like you're expecting `users` to be an array rather than a dictionary, but then you're casting it as a dictionary.  Without knowing your database schema it's hard to say what's actually happening.

But, you most likely want to actually turn your [String:AnyObject] into your actual data type.  There are a number of approaches to this, but you may have to write your own decoder.

You may want to add more information about what database you're actually using.

**Update**: Including an example method for turning your dictionary into your object:

```
class User: NSObject {
    var userID: String
    var fullname: String
    var imagePath: String

    required init(withDictionary dict : [String: AnyObject]) {
        userID = (dict["userID"] as? String) ?? ""
        fullname = (dict["fullname"] as? String) ?? ""
        imagePath = (dict["imagePath"] as? String) ?? ""
    }
}
```

Note that I'm not handling failures -- just putting in empty strings.

You can also look into storing making your model `Codable` compliant and try to convert in and out of JSON.  See: [How can I use Swift’s Codable to encode into a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45209743/how-can-i-use-swift-s-codable-to-encode-into-a-dictionary)

Comment: Yes I am wrestling with Firebase (realtime db).  So what is the easiest way to deal with this object?  Is it easiest to map users into a Dictionary?  I tried to cast users to STRING: Users but that was a failed attempt - "Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM'"

Comment: for (key,value) in users {
                print (users)
            }
does print out all users and their fields

Comment: You can't cast directly from AnyObject because Firebase doesn't know anything about how to convert.  You will probably have to write an initializer method that takes a [String: AnyObject] and converts it to your fields.  Will edit my answer in a second...

Comment: Thanks.  Or is it eaiser to forget the OBJECT and just define a dictionary?

Comment: That’s your choice depending on how you use it. If my answer helped please feel free to upvote/accept