# SwiftUI load json unknown levels of nested arrays

Tags: json, swiftui

I'm completely new on SwiftUI and trying to load a json file with data containing a tree structure with items of this type:

```
struct Node : Identifiable {
 id = UUID()
 name : String
 childNodes : [Node]
}
```

It is unknown beforehand how deep the data structure goes with child nodes.

Have tried to just decode

```
guard let results = try? decoder.decode(Node.self, from: filedata) else {
            fatalError("Decode error")
```

which seems to work, until I try to use the data. Guess it might have to do with the fact that the childNodes array is empty at some level.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: What does not work? Replace `try?` with `try` and a `do - catch` block and print the `error`. And your struct does not conform to `Decodable` anyway

Comment: You'll need to show the JSON. I expect that at some point you're missing the `childNodes` element, which your struct requires. If it can be missing (rather than empty), then it needs to be an Optional `childNodes: [Node]?`, or you need to use a custom init to decode this (which is generally my preferred solution over optional arrays). But I doubt the problem is the nesting itself. (Agreed with vadian that you shouldn't use `try?` if you can help it here. It just throws away the error that you need to debug this.)

Comment: Yes, I think a custom init would be the best way, but not sure how to do that. The sample JSON I use to try to load is just like this: {
    "name" : "Root",
    "id" : 0,
    "nodes" : [
    {
        "name" : "First child",
        "id" : 1,
        "nodes" : []
    }]
}

Comment: One potential issue is that in Swift you have childNodes in your Node struct. This looks like it should correspond to "nodes" in JSON. This could lead to problems with decoding as they are not exactly the same name. 

As mentioned above, you should try to conform to the "Codable" Protocol. This will encapsulate encodable and decodable. I recommend further reading on this. Doing this will also allow you to have custom coding keys by declaring 

```private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
case childNodes = "nodes"
}
```

Comment: Made it work with a custom init and "if-else" with decodeIfPresent

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but I solved a [vaguely similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66125305/how-do-i-correctly-serialize-deserialize-a-complex-swift-object-to-as-an-aws-lam) by using old-fashioned `JSONSerialization`. By casting to `[String : Any]` you don't need to know the structure of the nested objects. It is less clean to dig into them, but that's the trade-off:

```swift
guard let results = try JSONSerialization
    .jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any] else {
    print("didn't work")
    return 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the key `nodes` exists in any dictionary and an empty array is represented by `[]` then the JSON can be decoded simply with this struct

```
struct Node : Decodable {
    let id : Int
    let name : String
    let nodes : [Node]
}
```

For convenience you can add a computed property to indicate that the node is a *leaf*

```
struct Node : Decodable {
    let id : Int
    let name : String
    let nodes : [Node]
    
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case id, name, nodes }

    var isLeaf : Bool { return nodes.isEmpty }
}
```