# Add an array to a dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, loops, dictionary

i want to add more items to parameters, but for loop overwrite the exist data.

How can I add more item to parameters with loop?

```
var parameters: [String: Any] = [:]
let array = [1111,1112,1113,1114]
for product in array{
            parameters["line_items"] = [
            ["product_id": product, "quantity": 1]
        ]
        }
```

Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign an array of dictionaries to the `line_items` key. You can easily do that using `map` on `products`.

```
var parameters: [String: Any] = [:]
let products = [1111,1112,1113,1114]
parameters["line_items"] = products.map { product in ["product_id": product, "quantity": 1]}

print(parameters)
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should create the array for the `line_items` key first, then assign it to the dictionary:

```
var lineItems = [Any]()
for product in array{
    lineItems.append(
        ["product_id": product, "quantity": 1]
    )
}
parameters["line_items"] = lineItems
```

But as Dávid Pásztor said, you can just do a `map`:

```
parameters["line_items"] = array.map {
    ["product_id": $0, "quantity": 1]
}
```

If you have a `Codable` struct that contains this data,

```
struct LineItems : Codable {
    let lineItems: [Product]
}

struct Product : Codable {
    let productId: Int
    let quantity: Int
}
```

I would also recommend that you use the `DictionaryEncoder` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52308446/5133585) to create the entire dictionary.

```
let encoder = DictionaryEncoder()
encoder.keyEncodingStrategy = .convertToSnakeCase
let parameters = try encoder.encode(object)
```