# Turn Codable data into a `[String: CustomStringConvertible]` dictionary

Tags: swift, codable

This is similar to for example this question: [How can I use Swift’s Codable to encode into a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45209743/how-can-i-use-swift-s-codable-to-encode-into-a-dictionary#46329055), except that I want to specifically turn it into a `[String: CustomStringConvertible]` dictionary and I am not able to.

```swift
struct Model: Codable {
  let a: String
  let b: Int
}

let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(Model(a: "a", b: 1))
let parameters = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .allowFragments)
parameters as? [String: CustomStringConvertible] // nil
```

How can I make this work? This for example *does* work, which should work the same you'd think:

```swift
let dict: Any = ["a": "a", "b": 1]
dict as? [String: CustomStringConvertible] // ["a": "a", "b": 1]
```

Comment: I am curious why you would need this?

Comment: Because I need these dictionaries to be Equatable, which `[String: CustomStringConvertible]` is super handy for. And they fit the kind of data I'm working with, so win win :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to compare objects for equality instead of comparing dictionaries? `CustomStringConvertible` is maybe handy but it won't give always correct results. Sounds a bit like a javascripty solution.

Comment: Is that really a win win? 1 and "1" will be considered equal which isn't exactly true and a custom type (as value) that conforms to both Equatable and CustomStringConvertible will be compared using the latter protocol

Comment: It's for HTTP endpoint parameters where it doesn't matter if we compare "1" and 1, and yeah there's a reason for all of this, which is hard to explain in just a simple SO question.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to first cast it to `[String: AnyObject]` and THEN to `[String: CustomStringConvertible]`:

```swift
struct Model: Codable {
  let a: String
  let b: Int
}

let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(Model(a: "a", b: 1))
let parameters = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject] as? [String: CustomStringConvertible]
```

Weird, but it works ‍♂️